# How to properly export a const in Jscodeshift

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I am writing my first codemod using Jscodeshift.
My current goal is to export a const that is assigned a certain identifier.

So that, if I target every variable named `stuff`, it will be named-exported after the script runs.

IN:

```js
const stuff = 4;
```

OUT:

```js
export const stuff = 4;
```

This is a stripped down version of what I have. It *sort of* works but it looks very brittle and has a number of drawbacks.

```js
const constName = "stuff";

module.exports = (fileInfo, api) => {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;
  const root = j(fileInfo.source);

  const declaration = root.find(j.VariableDeclaration, {
    declarations: [
      {
        id: {
          type: "Identifier",
          name: constName
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  declaration.forEach(n => {
    n.insertBefore("export");
  });

  return root.toSource();
};
```

[AST](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/67b195609bd8820eb571e873d46ae920/27214f048343689b8c08eafee777d4810a5c0950)

This will result in (notice the unwanted new line)

```js
export
const stuff = 4;
```

This also crucially fails if this source is fed to the script.

IN:

```
// hey
const stuff = 4;
```

OUT:

```js
export
// hey
const stuff = 4;
```

I am quite convinced that `n.insertBefore("export");` is really the culprit here, and I'd like to build the named export myself using jscodeshift builders but really can't get it work.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.insertBefore` is not the right method to use. This is for inserting a whole new node before another node.

How want to *replace* a `VariableDeclaration` with an `ExportNamedDeclaration`. If you look at the AST for `export const stuff = 4;` you can see that it has a property `declaration` whose value is a `VariableDeclaration` node. That makes the transformation easy for us: Find the `VariableDeclaration`, create a new `ExportNamedDeclaration`, set it's `declaration` property to the found node and replace the found node with the new node.

To find out how to build the node we can look at [`ast-type`'s ast definitions](https://github.com/benjamn/ast-types/blob/c208a17d7eeef6a9676990d364f9236e8b7e512f/def/esprima.ts#L52).

```
const constName = "stuff";

module.exports = (fileInfo, api) => {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;

  return j(fileInfo.source)
    .find(j.VariableDeclaration, {
      declarations: [
        {
          id: {
            type: "Identifier",
            name: constName
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    .replaceWith(p => j.exportDeclaration(false, p.node))
    .toSource();
};
```

[astexplorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/2a340060310c675dc4dca8cb1f6a2b08/103b69688b9880e0b8835c82a78e33ace0496c11)

Comment: Hi Felix, if I could I'd upvote this twice because 1) it provides the correct answer and 2) it explains and clarifies to me the correct approach to solve similar problems with Codeshift in the future. 
Many thanks for taking the time to provide an answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome :) As an aside, in general you can also use the tagged templates `j.template.expression` and `j.template.statement` to create new nodes, but there are restrictions. `j.template.statement\`export ${p.node}\`` doesn't work unfortunately.